# AutoCorrelation in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a two column data frame where X is a set of data and Y is the data one row ahead.  For example:

```
X  Y
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

This is the code that I am using....any hints on how to accomplish this?

```
while intCount < (len(autoCorrelation_df["X"]) - 2):
#   autoCorrelation_df["Y"] = data.Error[+intCount]
    autoCorrelation_df["Y"][intCount] = autoCorrelation_df["X"][intCount - 1]
    print(intCount)
    intCount = intCount + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that this can help.... this is how I created the autocorrelation

```
autoCorrelation_df["Y"] = data.Error
autoCorrelation_df["X"] = np.NaN

while intCount < (len(autoCorrelation_df["Y"]) - 1):
    #autoCorrelation_df["Y"] = data.Error[+intCount]
    autoCorrelation_df["X"][intCount] = autoCorrelation_df["Y"][(intCount + 1)]
    intCount = intCount + 1
```